# Select all records where function is false

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function

I have a validation function that I'd like to run on each id in a table, and return only those ids which are invalid. Code that I've tried:

```
select  myID 
from myDB.dbo.myTable
where (myDB.dbo.validateID(myID) = 0)
```

Where myDB.dbo.validateID is a scalar-valued function.

This works but returns null for all the valid IDs - I want to only return the invalid ones. What is the most efficient way to return all the invalid rows using this function?

**Update:**

The validateID function returns 1 if the ID is valid, 0 if it isn't.

My code above returns null if the ID is valid, and the ID if it's not. I want it to instead only return the invalid IDs, without all the null results.

Comment: How the function differentiate Valid and Invalid Id's in the output?

Comment: @Pradeep - it returns 1 for valid, 0 for invalid. I'll update the post

Comment: In that case your query should work fine.

Comment: Can you post the Function code? Secondly, using a scalar-valued function in a query like this has serious performance issues since the function is evaluated for each returned row. So it is advised to avoid such usage. Instead, create a Table-Valued function and use `CROSS APPLY` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> select  myID 
> from myDB.dbo.myTable
> where (myDB.dbo.validateID(myID) = 0)
> ```
>
> This works but returns null for all the valid IDs

That is simply not possible. If you select `myID`, you get `myID`, so if you get `null`, then `myID` must be `null`, and your `validateID` function is detecting that as invalid.

If your function should treat `null` as a valid ID, you need to fix your function so that `myDB.dbo.validateID(null)` returns `1`.

If your function should treat `null` as neither a valid nor an invalid ID, you need to fix your function so that `myDB.dbo.validateID(null)` returns `null`.

If your function should treat `null` as an invalid ID, but you still want to exclude `null` results, when just add a condition `myID is not null` to your selection.

Comment: Thanks, you're right - there were null IDs (this is not actually the ID of the table). Thanks for identifying my issue, I feel silly for missing that :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same logic but am getting proper output as expected. Am getting rows returned only when function outputs 0 `(ie) Invalid records`. I don't see `NULL` values for `valid records`.

```
create table dbo.Contracts1(id int,name varchar(50),pric int)
INSERT INTO dbo.Contracts1
VALUES     ( 1,'invalid',40000),
            (2,'valid',50000),
            (3,'valid',35000),
            (4,'invalid',40000)

CREATE FUNCTION Testt(@id INT)
returns INT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @ret INT
      IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM   dbo.Contracts1
                 WHERE  name = 'Valid'
                        AND id = @id)
        SELECT @ret = 1
      ELSE
        SELECT @ret = 0
      RETURN @ret
  END

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.Contracts1
WHERE  dbo.Testt(id) = 0
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id   name    pric
--  ------- -----
1   invalid 40000
4   invalid 40000
```